# Haskell "Not a data constructor"

Tags: haskell, types

Im trying my first steps in Haskell, and wanted to define my own parameterized Data type.
Lets assume i have the following:

```
data Sth x = Foo x | Bar x
t1 :: Sth Int
t1 = Foo 5
t2 :: Sth Int
t2 = Bar 5
```

this is a correct definition, right? (At least i tried something like this).
But now, i wanted to give my 'Sth' the possibility to be only 'x', so I want to write something like this:

```
t3 :: Sth Int
t3 = 5
```

I tried:

```
data Sth x = Foo x | Bar x | x
```

but I get the error "not a data constructor: x"

Why?

Comment: You can find answer on question why not just `x` in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058506/why-does-maybe-include-just

Comment: oh, i wasnt able to find this question... thank you!