# Monad "unboxing"

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

My question came up while following the tutorial [*Functors, Applicatives, And Monads In Pictures*](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html) and its [JavaScript version](https://medium.com/@tzehsiang/javascript-functor-applicative-monads-in-pictures-b567c6415221#.rdwll124i).

When the text says that functor unwraps value from the context, I understand that a `Just 5` -> `5` transformation is happening. As per [What does the "Just" syntax mean in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808258/what-does-the-just-syntax-mean-in-haskell) , Just is "defined in scope" of the `Maybe` monad.

My question is what is so magical about the whole unwrapping thing? I mean, what is the problem of having some language rule which automatically unwraps the "scoped" variables? It looks to me that this action is merely a lookup in some kind of a table where the symbol `Just 5` corresponds to the integer `5`.

My question is inspired by the JavaScript version, where `Just 5` is prototype array instance. So unwrapping is, indeed, not rocket science at all.

Is this a "for-computation" type of reason or a "for-programmer" one? Why do we distinguish `Just 5` from `5` on the programming language level?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, I don't think you can understand Monads and the like without understanding a Haskell like type system (i.e. without learning a language like Haskell). Yes, there are many tutorials that claim otherwise, but I've read a lot of them before learning Haskell and I didn't get it. So my advice: If you want to understand Monads learn at least some Haskell.

To your question "Why do we distinguish `Just 5` from `5` on the programming language level?". For type safety. In most languages that happen not to be Haskell `null`, `nil`, `whatever`, is often used to represent the absence of a value. This however often results in things like `NullPointerExceptions`, because you didn't anticipate that a value may not be there.

In Haskell there is no `null`. So if you have a value of type `Int`, or anything else, that value can not be `null`. You are guarantied that there is a value. Great! But sometimes you actually want/need to encode the absence of a value. In Haskell we use `Maybe` for that. So something of type `Maybe Int` can either be something like `Just 5` or `Nothing`. This way it is explicit that the value may not be there and you can not accidentally forget that it might be `Nothing` because you have to explicitly unwrap the value.

This has nothing really to do with Monads, except that `Maybe` happens to implement the Monad type class (a type class is a bit like a Java interface, if you are familiar with Java). That is Maybe is not primarily a Monad, but just happens to also be a Monad.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking at this from the wrong direction.  `Monad` is explicitly *not* about unwrapping.  `Monad` is about composition.

It lets you combine (not necessarily apply) a function of type `a -> m b` with a value of type `m a` to get a value of type `m b`.  I can understand where you might think the obvious way to do that is unwrapping the value of type `m a` into an value of type `a`.  But very few `Monad` instances work that way.  In fact, the only ones that can work that way are the ones that are equivalent to the `Identity` type.  For nearly all instances of `Monad`, it's just not possible to unwrap a value.

Consider `Maybe`.  Unwrapping a value of type `Maybe a` into a value of type `a` is impossible when the starting value is `Nothing`.  Monadic composition has to do something more interesting than just unwrapping.

Consider `[]`.  Unwrapping a value of type `[a]` into a value of type `a` is impossible unless the input just happens to be a list of length 1. In every other case, monadic composition is doing something more interesting than unwrapping.

Consider `IO`.  A value like `getLine :: IO String` doesn't contain a `String` value.  It's plain impossible to unwrap, because it isn't wrapping something.  Monadic composition of `IO` values doesn't unwrap anything. It combines `IO` values into more complex `IO` values.

I think it's worthwhile to adjust your perspective on what `Monad` means. If it were only an unwrapping interface, it would be pretty useless. It's more subtle, though. It's a composition interface.

Answer (score 3):

A possible example is this: consider the Haskell type `Maybe (Maybe Int)`. Its values can be of the following form

- `Nothing`
- `Just Nothing`
- `Just (Just n)` for some integer `n`

Without the `Just` wrapper we couldn't distinguish between the first two.

Indeed, the whole point of the optional type `Maybe a` is to add a new value (`Nothing`) to an existing type `a`. To ensure such `Nothing` is indeed a fresh value, we wrap the other values inside `Just`.

It also helps during type inference. When we see the function call `f 'a'` we can see that `f` is called at the type `Char`, and not at type `Maybe Char` or `Maybe (Maybe Char)`. The typeclass system would allow `f` to have a different implementation in each of these cases (this is similar to "overloading" in some OOP languages).

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, what is so magical about the whole unwrapping thing?

There is nothing magical about it. You can use garden-variety pattern matching (here in the shape of a `case` expression) to define...

```
mapMaybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
mapMaybe f mx = case mx of
    Just x -> Just (f x)
    _ -> mx
```

... which is exactly the same than `fmap` for `Maybe`. The only thing the `Functor` class adds -- and it is a very useful thing, make no mistake -- is an extra level of abstraction that covers various structures that can be mapped over.

> Why do we distinguish `Just 5` from `5` on programming language level?

More meaningful than the distinction between `Just 5` and `5` is the one between their *types* -- e.g. between `Maybe Int`and `Int`. If you have `x :: Int`, you can be certain `x` is an `Int` value you can work with. If you have `mx :: Maybe Int`, however, you have no such certainty, as the `Int` might be missing (i.e. `mx` might be `Nothing`), and the type system forces you to acknowledge and deal with this possibility.

See also: [jpath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40830740/2751851) for further comments on the usefulness of `Maybe` (which isn't necessarily tied to classes such as `Functor` and `Monad`); [Carl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40831969/2751851) for further comments on the usefulness of classes like `Functor` and `Monad` (beyond the `Maybe` example).

Answer (score 1):

What "unwrap" means depends on the container. `Maybe` is just one example. "Unwrapping" means something completely different when the container is `[]` instead of `Maybe`.

The magical about the whole unwrapping thing is the abstraction: In a Monad we have a notion of "unwrapping" which abstracts the nature of the container; and then it starts to get "magical"...

You ask what `Just` means: Just is nothing but a Datatype constructor in Haskell defined via a data declaration like :

```
 data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing
```

`Just` take a value of type `a` and creates a value of type `Maybe a`. It's Haskell's way to distinguigh values of type `a` from values of type `Maybe a`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to remove monads from your question. They have nothing to do this. Treat this articles as one of the points of view on the monads, maybe it does not suit you, you may still little understood in the type system that would understand monads in haskell.

And so, your question can be rephrased as: Why is there no implicit conversion `Just 5 => 5`? But answer is very simple. Because value `Just 5` has type `Maybe Integer`, so this value may would be `Nothing`, but what must do compiler in this case? Only programmer can resolve this situation.

But there is more uncomfortable question. There are types, for example, `newtype Identity a = Identity a`. It's just wrapper around some value. So, why is there no impliciti conversion `Identity a => a`?

The simple answer is - an attempt to realize this would lead to a different system types, which would not have had many fine qualities that exist in the current. According to this, it can be sacrificed for the benefit of other possibilities.