# Understanding 'maybe' in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, option-type

So say we have an example of a function sqrt that gives us the square root of a floating point number but does not abort on negative inputs. So what will be the type of sqrt.

I was told the answer is:

```
sqrt :: Maybe Float -> Float
```

however i do not understand what the Maybe does, does it simply mean that we can give anything as input or does it mean something else.

Comment: A `Maybe` is a parameterized type. And now you know as much as you did before.

Comment: `sqrt :: Float -> Maybe Float` sounds more reasonable. There may or may not be a valid result. That's what the `Maybe` type is about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "Just" syntax mean in Haskell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808258/what-does-the-just-syntax-mean-in-haskell)

Answer (score 7):

`Maybe` is a type constructor with a simple definition:

```
data Maybe a 
    = Just a  
    | Nothing
```

This syntax reads as "Create a new type constructor called `Maybe` which accepts one type parameter. It has two value constructors: `Just` which takes a single argument of type `a`, or `Nothing`."

When we are writing functions which accept a `Maybe` argument, then we can pattern match on that to handle both cases.

```
foo :: Maybe String -> String
foo (Just str) = str
foo Nothing = "There was nothing!"
```

If a function doesn't have a meaningful definition for all inputs, then we can use `Maybe` to say that. For example, `sqrt` in the Prelude returns `NaN` for negative values. We could write a different version that returned `Maybe`:

```
import qualified Prelude
import Prelude hiding (sqrt)

sqrt :: Float -> Maybe Float
sqrt x
    | x < 0     = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just (Prelude.sqrt x)
```

We might read that type as "If you give me a float, then I may be able to return a float."

Answer (score 0):

I have retracted my close vote, although the top answer on the other question more or less answers this one its not really a dupe per se.

First, lets talk about parameterized types.

If I say (language agnostic)

```
Array<String>
```

we have a array of strings. And an array of strings `["foo", "bar"]` *has the type* `Array<String>`. 'Array' by itself isn't really a complete type*, we have an array *of* something. In other words, we will parameterize `Array` with the type `String`.

`Maybe` works like this too, you have a (in this case) a `Maybe Float` which can be either `Just Float` or `Nothing`. Now, just like the compiler won't let you pass a list of ints to a function that takes an int, it won't let you pass a `Maybe T` to a function that takes type `T`. You have to deal with the `Nothing` case, the type system prevents omitting handling the failure case. So you're sqrt function should have signature

```
sqrt :: Float -> Maybe Float
```

To reflect the fact that although you can pass in any float, the result might not be there if the argument is negative.

* For the purposes of this discussion.